# No routes matched - React Router V6.8.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I Get `No routes matched location` error in my React JS To-do Application despite having followed all the steps required as per the Officia guide by the React Router website.

At first i though the issue lies in the Navbar component - maybe i'm not doing something correctly but even when i try to manualy edit the url to a certain route, i still get the same problem

All source code [here](https://github.com/artwaha/to-do)

**All components are imported correctly, i just chose not to include imports section**

Here is my **Index.js**:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    Children: [
      {
        path: "all-todos",
        element: <AllTodos />

      },
      {
        path: 'done',
        element: <Done />
      },
      {
        path: "todo",
        element: <Todo />
      },
    ]
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is **App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen'>
      <Navbar />
      <AddTask />
      <main className='flex-1 flex'>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is one of the Routes (**Done Component**)

```
const Done = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Done</h2>
    </>
  )
}

export default Done
```

Here is **Navbar**:

```
export default function Navbar() {
    const navigation = [
        { name: "All Tasks", path: "#" },
        { name: "Todo", path: "#" },
        { name: "Done", path: "#" },
    ];



    return (
        <div className="w-full border-b border-gray-200">
            <nav className="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between p-4 lg:justify-between">
                {/* Logo  */}
                <Disclosure>
                    {({ open }) => (
                        <>
                            <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-auto">
                                <Link to="#" className="flex font-extrabold items-center space-x-2 text-2xl text-indigo-500 dark:text-gray-100">
                                    To-do
                                </Link>

                                <Disclosure.Button
                                    aria-label="Toggle Menu"
                                    className="px-2 py-1 ml-auto text-gray-500 rounded-md lg:hidden hover:text-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500 focus:bg-indigo-100 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:focus:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:text-gray-300">
                                    <svg
                                        className="w-6 h-6 fill-current"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                        {open && (
                                            <path
                                                fillRule="evenodd"
                                                clipRule="evenodd"
                                                d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
                                            />
                                        )}
                                        {!open && (
                                            <path
                                                fillRule="evenodd"
                                                d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </svg>
                                </Disclosure.Button>

                                <Disclosure.Panel className="flex flex-wrap w-full my-5 lg:hidden">
                                    <>
                                        {navigation.map((item, index) => (
                                            **<Link key={index} to={item.path} className="w-full px-4 py-2 -ml-4 text-gray-500 rounded-md dark:text-gray-300 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500 focus:bg-indigo-100 focus:outline-none dark:focus:bg-gray-700">
                                                {item.name}
                                            </Link>**
                                        ))}
                                    </>
                                </Disclosure.Panel>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Disclosure>

                {/* menu  */}
                <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:items-center">
                    <ul className="items-center justify-end flex-1 pt-6 lg:pt-0 list-reset lg:flex">
                        {navigation.map((menu, index) => (
                            <li className="mr-3 nav__item" key={index}>
                                **<Link to={menu.path.toString()} className="inline-block p-2 font-normal text-gray-800 no-underline rounded-md dark:text-gray-200 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500 focus:bg-indigo-100 focus:outline-none">
                                    {menu.name}
                                </Link>**
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think  the `Children` property is supposed to be capitalised, is that a typo?

Comment: Hahah thanks...that was it! However, is there a way to make a partiular element(Route) as the default one in the <Outlet/> - because initially its blank untill i navigate to one of the route elements.

Comment: You've a typo in the routes config, it's `children`, not `Children`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to write your `Children` property with lowercase

Comment: Hahah thanks...that did it! However, is there a way to make a partiular element(Route) as the default element in the <Outlet/> - because initially the Outlet in the Layout is all blank untill i navigate to one of the route elements.